# Customised Dropdown column using sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, drop-down-menu, extensible

I have tried normal dropdown column in sharepoint. I want to customise that column with extensible kind of dropdown. Is that possible in anyway? The output I want should be in the form of the below image.

[image]

Comment: What is "extensible kind of dropdown"??

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you want to achieve, but in general:

SharePoint has different data types. The Choice and the Lookup data types both show as a dropdowns in the out-of-the-box SharePoint user interface.

Different user interface presentations can be achieved with tools that modify the presentation. The tools available differ considerably, depending on the SharePoint version.

For SharePoint online, for example, you can use PowerApps to change or style standard controls.